# Navigation bar getting access to other viewControllers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a navigationController w/navigationBar and  that is always displayed at the top of my app. I have two buttons on the navigation bar that when clicked perform certain actions.  What I am having issues with is when the users clicks one of the buttons I need the navigationcontroller to somehow call a method on the uiviewcontroller that is currently in charge of the view in content area.

So how my app is setup is that the navbar has its own navigationbarcontroller and the view, visually below the navbar, has its own uiviewcontroller.

I need to know how to access a method in the uiviewcontroller or any uiviewcontroller that is currently visible/active.

Would I setup a class method in the UIViewController class and call it? Or would I somehow get the instance of the UIViewController that is currently active and call an instance method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either would work, but I think getting an instance and using a normal method would be preferred since the Class method cannot access properties of the instance.

Comment: How do you go about getting the instance.  Is the proper way to setup vars in your delegate for each viewcontroller created or maybe just the active ones then set those vars, in the delegate, from the viewcontrollers ability to always access the delegate?